# Is it possible to copy the course to make a custom copy of a standard Acumatica function?

Tags: acumatica

I've got a situation that we would like to be able to customize the SO Copy Order function (specifically we would like to copy only a certain set of details and make some changes to the header as it copies).

I was hoping that I could just view the source and then, find `CopyOrder` and `CopyOrderProc` and drop those into my graph extension and custom menu structure. The menu part is worked out just fine, but CopyOrderProc leaves me with lots of compile issues though (tried removing the parameters it sends, as I'll really just need to copy and will have fixed options. Seems like my errors start with the `.Select(this, sourceOrder.OrderType)`, which is, you know, the first real line.)

Is that something I should be able to do and just don't understand something, or is that way beyond what's possible?

Comment: First, you need to replace all occurrence of "this" with "Base" in your copied codes. Then any references to a view, you;ll need to append Base e.g. Document to Base.Document. Base is the graph you're trying to extend. Not to be confused with "base" - lower letter b. Which is a parent class.

Comment: Thanks! That's super helpful. Looks like the next place I get hung up is `OrderCreated`. Is there a way to refer to the one that exists or do I need to copy it into my custom code as well? For what it's worth, it looks like this: `public delegate void OrderCreatedDelegate(SOOrder document, SOOrder source);
  protected virtual void OrderCreated(SOOrder document, SOOrder source)
  {

  }`

Answer (score 1):

Most customized acumatica functions are listed in the App_Data\CodeRepository folder of your Acumatica instance. Loading any extension library allows you to browse and search these through Visual Studio.

Looking at the CopyOrder function, it calls the CopyOrderProc function. Delegates are done with a PXOverride flag and a copy of the parameters as a delegate. Here is an example of your override:

```
    public delegate void CopyOrderProcDelegate(SOOrder sourceOrder, CopyParamFilter copyFilter);
    [PXOverride]        
    public virtual void CopyOrderProc(SOOrder sourceOrder, CopyParamFilter copyFilter, CopyOrderProcDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        //code before the base method is called, like validation/prevention.

        baseMethod(sourceOrder, copyFilter);

        //code after the base method is called
    }
```

You must override the final function that is called as other parts of the code may call this function rather than the action. I have InvoiceOrder overridden in one of my customization projects to both validate that it can be created, as well as perform actions after the base method is called and works great.